# Four div (25%) in a row with border

Tags: jquery, html, css, border

I'm trying to make a line with 4 elements, each with 25% width. So I did, but when trying to place an item in with border, everything goes wrong and I can not make it work.

The idea is as the picture, got on top of each box, and the rest a text with other text.

The second image shows the layout in the default browse.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/wwvhL/2/

```
.box.container
{
  height : 310px; 
  width : 25%;
  float: left;    
}

.box.interno
{
  background-color: #babaca;  
  padding: 25px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}

.box.item
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border:thin solid black;

}
```

[image: div width:25px for box]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you add items in the border? In what way is it not working?

Comment: he comes out of the div "box container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this might help:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```